# Error concerning host name in Eclipse Mobilefirst

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I get this error every time I try to deploy an adapter. The error says:

> Host name may not be blank

I was able to verify from `MobileFirst Development Server` window, that the *Server name* and *Host name* are correct. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's more related to the adapter than the server.
Make sure to properly supply the backend server URL in the adapter XML file.

Comment: That worked great. There was a little mistake in the domain name and it's resolved !
Thank you